# Is automated web site access legal?

Tags: automation, privacy, legal, bots, robots.txt

Many web sites include in their terms of service things about automated access being prohibited.  One example is in ebay's robots.txt file:

> The use of robots or other automated means to access the eBay site\n
>   without the express permission of eBay is strictly prohibited.
>   Notwithstanding the foregoing, eBay may permit automated access to
>   access certain eBay pages but soley for the limited purpose of
>   including content in publicly available search engines. Any other
>   use of robots or failure to obey the robots exclusion standards set
>   forth at  is strictly
>   prohibited.

What does their prohibition of automated access actually mean?  Does it make automated access illegal or just frowned upon?

Comment: This is a legal question that depends on your jurisdiction, not a technical one.

Comment: I agree this is offtopic, but here's general guidelines, though: if you accept EULA (for example, register user you're planning to use for scraping), its contents are binding on most jurisdictions.